# PHP within javascript for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying to solve my issue of creating a dropdown menu within a javascript, but using PHP data.  I know that you can't "run" PHP within a javascript, but have not been able to solve my issue.  My goal is to give the ability to add more items to a form on the fly. I have it working just fine without the dropdown menu, so below is all the code that I think it needed. This is what I started with and I have tried multiple fixes, without any luck.

Thank you for your input!

```
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<div style=\"float:left; width:200px;\"><select name=\"Room_Type\" style=\"width:200px;\" tabindex=\""+counter+"\">";

              newdiv.innerHTML .= "<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Select one</option>";
<?php
        if ($Total_Rows != 0) {

            $Run_Cnt = 0;

            while ($Run_Cnt < $Total_Rows): ?>

                newdiv.innerHTML .= "<option value=\""+<?=$Room_Type_List[$Run_Cnt]['ID']; ?>+"\">"+<?= stripslashes($Room_Type_List[$Run_Cnt]['Type_Name']); ?>+"</option>";<?php
            $Run_Cnt++;  
            endwhile;

        } ?>
        newdiv.innerHTML .= "</select></div>";
```

Comment: `tabindex="\""+counter+"\"` You have an extra quote here.

Comment: I noticed you used `newdiv.innerHTML .=` The `.=` operator is php's append operator. I believe you need the Javascript append operator which is `+=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never concatenate data directly into a script.  It must be escaped properly for it work.  `stripslashes()` is not enough.  In your code, you are outputting data from PHP into JavaScript, and then in JavaScript into HTML.  This will only lead to headache.

In your case, I think you will find it best to send your room type data to JavaScript, and then assemble your elements in JavaScript client-side.

```
<script>
  // Use JSON-encoding, which is compatible with JavaScript
  var roomTypes = <?php echo json_encode($Room_Type_List); ?>;

  // Now, all of your room data is available to use directly within JavaScript
  console.log(roomTypes);

  // Build your HTML here

</script>
```

Now, when you build your HTML, be sure to set the attributes and text.  **Never** concatenate data in as HTML, unless that data actually is HTML.  Use `el.setAttribute()` and `el.textContent()`.  Text can be tricky, so I usually just use jQuery's `.text()`.

Comment: Not to mention, then once this is done it's very easy to switch to grabbing roomTypes via XHR. :)

Comment: As I am not that good at javascript, how would I then take the roomTypes variable and have it looped through for the dropdown menu as well as use the various parts of the array information stored within roomTypes?

Comment: @Kaleb I suggest using jQuery's `$.each()`.